# Определить язык браузера (системы) в chrome extention

Tags: chrome-extension

Я создаю расширение для Google Chrome, и мне нужно в background script определить язык браузера который установлен у пользователя (не страницы которая открыта, а именно браузера).

Как это сделать? Буду очень благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Можно так:

```
var language = window.navigator ? (window.navigator.language ||
                  window.navigator.systemLanguage ||
                  window.navigator.userLanguage) : "ru";
language = language.substr(0, 2).toLowerCase();
```

Или так:

```
var userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage; 
console.log(userLang);
```

Answer (score 0):

Оказывается все очень просто:

```
chrome.i18n.getUILanguage()
```